# Using OpenDNS on my local NAT to resolve specific domain

Tags: router, dns, nat, domain-name, opendns

My home router, a ZyXEL C2100Z, does not support NAT loopback, which leaves me in a bind when trying to access a site from my iPhone that I am serving publicly from a server within my home network.

When I am not at home, I can go to my site from the public internet and everything works fine. When I am at home connected to my network, I have to use a different address to get to this same server. My router supports Host mapping, so rather than going to mydomainname.com like I would on the public internet, I navigate to mydomainname, and I have my web server serving at both of those host names. This is a workaround, but certainly not my ideal solution.

On my laptop, this problem could be easily fixed by editing the hosts file, but I am trying to fix this problem specifically for *the iPhones* on my network. I am not interested in rooting the phones.

What I am wondering is if I can get around this problem by installing a DNS like OpenDNS on my home server and making my local network use that to resolve domain names, and just put in a single `A` entry for my public site to route back to the local IP, and fallback to my ISP's DNS for everything else. If I do this I am assuming I just configure my router to use my local DNS server instead of my ISP's DNS server.

1. Is this possible? (i.e. is that how it works?)
2. Is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

(Please know that I have seen similar questions with similar answers, but I am specifically distinguishing this question from others because I am wondering all ways to accomplish this specific scenario, iPhones on a NAT network with no NAT loopback.)

Comment: I realize one solution to this is to point my domain to a completely different server (outside the network, maybe AWS) that just acts as a reverse proxy for my server. I am wondering about free/low cost options for that. If I use a reverse proxy, then I have to be able to configure my SSL certificates on that server.

Comment: This problem will go away if you use IPv6. From your question I cannot tell if your router already has IPv6 turned on. That's the first thing you should check.

Comment: So IPv6 as I understand does not sit behind a NAT (partly because there is no scarcity of addresses in the v6 space), so if I eliminate the NAT then I am eliminating an extra tremendous level of security, because now all devices on my network face exposure. That creates a whole new problem.

Comment: If you assume NAT is a security measure, you are doing things wrong. You can configure a firewall if you want to limit what's reachable.